# Blog RSS feed has incorrect URLs

Tags: bug, feed, blog

The [RSS feed](https://blog.stackexchange.com/feed/) has invalid URLs on the blog.

[image: Blog Feeds]

The URL for the most recent post in the feed is:

```
http://stackexchange.github.io/blog/2015/07/announcing-stackexchange-precompilation/
```

This returns a 404.

The real URL is

```
https://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/07/announcing-stackexchange-precompilation/
```

It appears that the domain is incorrect in the feeds. Can this be corrected?

Comment: I can't repro this or I am looking at the wrong stuff...

Comment: It appears to have been resolved. My assumption is that when the new blog post was rendered [_config.yml](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/blob/master/_config.yml) was used instead of [_blog.config.yml](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/blob/master/_blog.config.yml). The first has the github domain, the second does not.

Comment: OK, that seems like a logical explanation.